# Trouble with Concatenation in Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to generate dynamic CSS ids for javascript purposes, and the following code is giving me an error:

```
<%= form_for @item, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :item_images do |builder| %>
        <%= image_tag builder.object.image.url(:large), :class => "cropbox", 'data-id' => builder.object.id %>
        <% for attribute in [:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h] %>
            <%= builder.text_field attribute, :id => attribute + builder.object.id %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I know I'm not concatenating attribute and builder.object.id properly, but I've tried everything with no luck.  I get this error message:

**undefined method `+' for :crop_x:Symbol**

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your expected result?
Can you p out what '''attribute''' is within your expression?
Also, have you tried `.concat` instead of '+'?

Away from my desk, but my suggestion is something like:
Example:

```
attribute.concat(builder.object.id)
```

Maybe need to convert `attribute.to_i` or `.to_s` into a responsive type or create a different dynamic CSS id solution

Comment: expected result the id should be like "crop_x01" etc. Attribute comes from the loop, just the four values of :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h.  Thanks for your suggestion I will try it out

Comment: This helped a lot, i used this to get it working - `attribute.to_s.concat(builder.object.id.to_s)`  Thanks for the help!